# Understanding to convert a multi-dimensional array to a one-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

There is a really good explanation of multi-dimensional array [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613429/algorithm-to-convert-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-a-one-dimensional-array) on stackoverflow which I have studied and researched but i have few follow up questions for anyone who wants to help out. This is not a HW question, it is out of my text book which I am trying to understand more **so please confirm if I am looking at the below example correctly. Thank you in advance.**

So if i had a 3 dimensional array such as this:

```
                  {{{'1','2'},{'3','4'}},
                   {{'5','6'},{'7','8'}},
                   {{'9','10'},{'11','12'}}};
```

`Would the one dimensional outcome (using c compiler) simply be?:
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 10  | 11  | 12  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
And the corresponding position as?
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| 0   | 1   | 2   | 3   | 4   | 5   | 6   | 7   | 8   | 9   | 10  | 11  |
|     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |     |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+`

Again I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613429/algorithm-to-convert-a-multi-dimensional-array-to-a-one-dimensional-array) link as my source. 
The only thing I am looking for as a form of answer is, **am I looking/doing this correctly? If not, I would appreciate it if you can tell me where I have made any mistakes. Thank you again.**

Comment: Any questions for me?

Comment: Yes, your understanding seems correct. You can check by traversing the array with a `char*`, printing one element at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
char [3][2][2] :

+-----+-----+         +-----+-----+
|+-----+-----+        |+-----+-----+
||   1 |   3 |        ||  4  |  5  |
||1,0+-----+-----+    ||   +-----+-----+
|+---|  a  |  b  |    |+---|  0  |  1  |
||  2|0,0,0|0,0,1|    ||  6|     |     |
+|1,1+-----+-----+ => +|   +-----+-----+
 +---|  x  |  y  |     +---|  2  |  3  |
     |0,1,0|0,1,1|         |     |     |
     +-----+-----+         +-----+-----+
```

so your outcome seems ok, and thus (2.) t3[0] should be a.

2.

if t2 looks like this, t2[0][1] is b:

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  a  |  b  |  x  |  y  |      |     |     |     |     |
|0,0,0|0,0,1|0,1,0|0,1,1|      | 0,0 | 0,1 | 0,2 | 0,3 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  3  |  2  |  7  |  =>  |     |     |     |     |
|1,0,0|1,0,1|1,1,0|1,1,1|      | 1,0 | 1,1 | 1,2 | 1,3 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+-----+-----+-----+
|  q  |  g  |  r  |  4  |      |     |     |     |     |
|2,0,0|2,0,1|2,1,0|2,1,1|      | 2,0 | 2,1 | 2,2 | 2,3 |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+      +-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

As long you are converting them the right way(as it seems according to the link) it should work...

Answer (score 0):

For conceptual understanding this is a good starting point.

But you should understand the difference between **row vs column major**. And technically it could vary between compilers and languages depending upon what they are designed for.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order